# Guidlines for (many and big) figures vs text placements in a long document

Tags: floats

I know this is a common issue and that it generates a lot of discussion. I read tons of topics/blogs here and there, but nothing really helped me.

I have a large document (with the `report` class) with *many* figures, and approximately half of these are code highlighted with minted. It is not really possible to reduce the size of the figures without affecting the readability of the document. I have tried many different methods to place these correctly, but there is always issues on the output:

- Vertical spaces between paragraphs and sections are insanely big. For instance, it happens that two 5 lines paragraphs are at the top and the bottom of a page. This occurs when I force figures placement with `[H]` or directives like `[!htbp]`.
- Some of the last words of a paragraph are placed alone at a top of the next page (also happen with `[H]`).
- Figures are moved very far, like several pages, from the section where they are declared (and so referenced). Consequently, the document become painful to read. For instance, I have a paragraph where I speak about the code with sentences like "as shown line *x* and *y* of the code figure 42...". And the figure is 3 pages later. This happens when I leave the placement of the figure to TeX.
- Mixing parameters like `[H]` and no indications made things even worse. Figures happen to be placed in a wrong order, or all at the end of the chapter.

My point is: is there some guidelines or a general approach to mitigate the most as possible these problems ? I know that it is better to wait for the document to be fully written, which is the case. Also I would like to avoid many tries since the document is very long.

I leave some screenshots of the output to illustrate my talk.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In gerenal avoid `[H]` and `[!h]` as they often lead to large gaps. Use e.g. `[htb]` instead. Use `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` at the end of a section / chapter to place all figure that weren't placed yet before the next section starts. Don't use figure environments for code snippets. For longer code snippets you could allow page breakes to minimize the gaps. If there are far too many images compared to the text and the text would no longer be easy to read (due to the gaps and interruptions), LaTeX pushes them to the end by default.

Comment: You could try using nothing but [p] for all your figures and tables.  Increasing `\floatpagefraction` (default 0.5) would decrease the wasted space but increase the number of pages needed to accumulate a full page worths of floats.  `\afterpage{\clearpage}`  could be useful there.

Comment: This package is your friend: https://ctan.org/pkg/fewerfloatpages

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try some of these solution and come back. @KeksDose what approach do you suggest using this package ? For instance what position specifier should I start with the figures ?

Comment: Without any [htbp whatever], but with `\usepackage[trace]{fewerfloatpages}` and read the log. Read the manual for the trace option. [p] demands placement of the figure on a float page, which probably isn't what you want.